# Trying to run cucumber using jruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, jruby, sikuli, sikuli-script

I am trying to run cucumber using jruby. Below is the command I am using:

`$ jruby -S cucumber`

It gives me the following error:

```
 Gem::LoadError: Could not find 'cucumber' (>= 0) among 20 total gem(s)  
 to_specs at /Users/shrivaw1/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.15/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency.rb:298
 to_spec at /Users/shrivaw1/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.15/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency.rb:309
 gem at /Users/shrivaw1/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.15/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47  
 (root) at /usr/bin/cucumber:22
```

When I try to run following command:

```
$ jgem install cucumber
```

or

```
$ jruby -S gem install cucumber
```

then I get below error

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)
setting default path failed: null
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I also tried adding cacert.pem using following command (found from google search) but it also didnt helped.

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/Users/{PATH}/cacert.pem
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue. I basically want to run Sikuli + Cucumber using jruby. (https://github.com/chaslemley/cucumber_sikuli)

Comment: try installing jruby-openssl first https://github.com/jruby/jruby-openssl

Comment: I am running following command: "$ jruby -S gem install jruby-openssl" and getting same error as above. Error loading command....

Answer (score 0):

update to latest 1.7.20 (or I believe at least 1.7.16 should do) and you should be good to go ... there were some nasty (default) gem visibility issues

Comment: I am on 1.7.20 and have the same problem.